# Unable to post data to foreign key table in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, foreign-keys

I am an absolute beginner to **Django** and I am trying to check the **POST** method by populating the value to the foreign key table. I have two tables. Please guide me on where I am wrong.

> 1. Table for Category that has 2 entries, i.e., Coffee(PK = 1) and Desserts (PK = 2)
> 2. Table for Items

[image]

**From models.py:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cId = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    categoryName = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryName
        # return[self.categoryName, self.cId]
        # return self.cId
    
class Item(models.Model):
    Id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    itemName  = models.CharField(max_length=30,unique=True)
    cId = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=CASCADE)
```

**From views.py:**
def main(request):
return render(request, "index.html")

```
def send(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        a = request.POST.get("a");
        b = request.POST.get("b");
        obj = Item(itemName = a, cId =b);
        obj.save()
        
        return HttpResponse("sent")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("form submission failed")
```

**From urls.py(app):**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.main, name="main"),
    path('send', views.send, name='send')
   
]
```

**From HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% load static %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css.css' %}">

    <title>CHECK-POST-METHOD</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class = "container">
        <form method = "post" action = "send" class = "form">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <label for="a">Item Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="a" id="a" maxlength="30">
            <label for="b">PASS FOREIGN KEY--CATEGORY ID</label>
            <input type="number" name="b" id="b" maxlength="5">
            <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>

        </form>

    </div>

    <script src="{% static 'js.js' %}"></script>
  
</body>

</html>
```

***I am unable to populate the Item table with the following entry:***
[image]

***I am unable to resolve the following error:***
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cId` expects a `Category` object, but you have given it `'1'`. If you want to specify the primary key instead for a `ForeignKey` named *`foo`*, you use `foo_id`, so in this case `cId_id`:

```
def send(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        a = request.POST.get('a')
        b = request.POST.get('b')
        obj = Item(itemName=a, cId_id=b)
        obj.save()
        
        return HttpResponse("sent")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("form submission failed")
```

Comment: on my Django admin none of the columns has this title, i.e., 'cId_id' but in my MySQL I have this "cId_id" attribute in my table that has items. Please guide how to identify the correct name of the attribute when one is using only django admin. Thank you.

Comment: @Hasnain: if you define a `ForeignKey`, Django will make a database column with `columnname_id` so with an `_id` suffix. This dus means that the data is stored in the `cId_id` column, and this is also an attribute to control the `ForeignKey`.

Comment: You said cId expects a Category object and I have understood this. Does itemName has been also assigned with the object or is it a string.

Comment: @Hasnain: it will call `str(...)` on the object, so you can pass any object, but it will convert it to a string (and it is not per se said that one can reconstruct the object if it is not a string).

Comment: let's suppose that the itemName has the "int" datatype in database. It would still convert it to string in this case? How the database column would receive it as an integer?

Comment: @Hasnain: in case it is an integer field, the database column is an integer field, and Django will call `int(..)` on the object before passing it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

As it indicates in the error, Cid must be instance of category
So your view looks like below:

```
def send(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        a = request.POST.get("a");
        b = request.POST.get("b");
        c_id = Category.objects.get(pk=b)
        obj = Item(itemName=a, cId=b);
        obj.save()

        return HttpResponse("sent")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("form submission failed")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `cId` needs to be an object of type `Category`, you can use Django's `get_object_or_404` function. In cases where `cId` posted from the HTML is not valid, then this function automatically raises the `404` response.

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def send(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        a = request.POST.get("a");
        b = request.POST.get("b");
        b_obj = get_object_or_404(Category, b)
        obj = Item(itemName = a, cId =b_obj)
        obj.save()
        
        return HttpResponse("sent")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("form submission failed")
```